# How to convert MS Excel numbers in general format (e.g 43390) to date in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, valueerror

please I need solution to this problem I have a field that is formatted in  e.g 43390 which is general date format in excel. I need to format it to a date like "d/m/yyy"

here is the code I wrote :

```
trans_ data['DATE'] = pd.to_ datetime(trans_ data['DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

but I have this error:

> ValueError: time data '43390' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' (match)

Comment: What is the date corresponding to 43390? 17/10/2018?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert the "43390" in LibreOffice and it converted it to `2018-10-17` (the origin `"0"` is "30/12/1899"):

```py
origin = pd.Timestamp("30/12/1899")
df["col"] = df["col"].apply(lambda x: origin + pd.Timedelta(days=x))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         col
0 2018-10-17
1 2019-11-02
```

---

`df` used:

```
     col
0  43390
1  43771
```

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can do without the apply, pd.to_datetime has all you need - see the dupe I linked.

Comment: @MrFuppes Yep, that answer is more to the depth :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help you.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

excel_date = '43390'
excel_date = int(excel_date)
python_date = pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01') + timedelta(excel_date-2)

print(python_date)
```

The `python_date` object stores the date. Then you can change the format to the format you need.

Comment: pandas also has a timedelta type. Other than that, you actually don't need it, see the dupe I linked.